# CMake forward declear libraries (OpenSSL)

Tags: cmake, openssl

I downloaded [janbar's OpenSSL Cmake](https://github.com/janbar/openssl-cmake), to be able to cross-compile my code that OpenSSL (More correct I use Curl that needs OpenSSL). I ran the OpenSSL CMake as a standalone and it compiled fine, and I got some library and executable files from it. I then wanted to include it into my project, at first I simply added the folder where I extracted the OpenSSL with CMakefiles as such: `add_subdirectory(openssl)`. This did not work as `find_package(OpenSSL)` will complain that:

```
Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY, missing: OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR) (found version "1.1.1g")
```

Here I did a bit of "Bad" CMake, as I knew where the include folder is and where the libraries would go so I did this at the end of the OpenSSL Cmake:

```
set(OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include" CACHE PATH "Path to include dir")
set(OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY "${CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/libcrypto.lib")
```

When configuring, this gives me a similar error:

```
Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY) (found version "1.1.1g")
```

The find function seems to be happy with my include, however it still complains about not finding the Crypto library. I know that the crypto .lib file will be created when building the OpenSSL. I have done this "forward declaration" before on other projects where the FindPackage fails due to looking in the wrong spot, or where the files have yet to be created. I am not certain why it fails, as I have had success with this in the past (despite it not being recommended practice).

I would love some pointer to what might be wrong but would be even better for some pointer to get it to work how I want: Compile OpenSSL together with my project using CMake.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Here I did a bit of "Bad" CMake ..." - What about do NOT do "bad"? Just **install** `OpenSSL` at some *installation prefix* and set variable `OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR` equal to this prefix, as the error message suggests.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Maybe It wasn't clear enough in the original question. I need it to be cross-platform, and self-contained. My other alternative (AFAIK) is to compile OpenSSL on all the platforms the software is going to be run on (Windows/Ubuntu/MacOs/Arm) and give that as root path.
I know it's "bad" CMake, but I am not sure what would be "good" CMake in this case (that keeps my wanted features)

Comment: `find_package` in most cases works only with **already installed** package, and OpenSSL package is not an exception. Of course, you may write your own `FindOpenSSL.cmake` script (which is used internally by `find_package(OpenSSL)`), which would work with OpenSSL included via `add_subdirectory` approach, but this requires some work and investigation of the existed `FindOpenSSL.cmake` script. Approach with pre-installed `OpenSSL` would be much simpler, both in initial coding and in the maintaining(the lesser you hack, the lesser you get maintenance problems).

Comment: Using **installed** OpenSSL doesn't automatically means that you **require** this installation from the user of your project. You may install OpenSSL as a part of your build script. You may install OpenSSL even inside your `CMakeLists.txt` via `execute_process` command. Just make sure you have OpenSSL installed at the time when `find_package(OpenSSL)` is called.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you! I got it to work using `execute_process`. By running an `execute_process` for both configuring and installing/building, where the given install directory argument became the `OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR`